# Check context of plugins to avoid to be loaded everywhere in Joomla!

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-5.x

In my component i have some plugins (like this one https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/blob/K6.2/src/plugins/plg_kunena_comprofiler/comprofiler.php), when there are enabled they cause issues with Akeeba Panopticon. It gives an error when it's enabled, the API Panopticon responds not as expected.

Expected results :

```
{"errors":[{"title":"Resource not found","code":404}]}
```

When plugin is enabled :

```
Unable to handle request for route ``.
```

How to check the context and avoid the plugins to be loaded everywhere in Joomla! ?

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33321/unloading-once-loaded-plugin-in-joomla-4 might give you some ideas.